# JPQL (Eclipse JPA procider) cannot call method on int

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jpa

So I have a the following JPQL in Netbean JPQL tool.

```
SELECT e.idEtu, e.nomEtu, e.prenomEtu,e.ddnEtu 
FROM Etudiant e,InscrireClasse i, Niveau n 
WHERE i.idNiveau = n.idNiveau  AND n.nomNiveau='Master 1'
```

When I run it I dont know why but there is a Bug. Below is the JPA log (it say cannot call method on int...no idea what it means)

if I run it without *i.idNiveau = n.idNiveau* it works perfectly

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]    (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:     Cannot call methods on int.
Error Code: 258
Call: SELECT t0.id_etu, t0.nom_etu, t0.prenom_etu, t0.ddn_etu FROM     GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.etudiant t0, GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.niveau t2, GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.InscrireClasse t1 WHERE ((t1.id_niveau = t2.id_niveau.t2.id_niveau) AND (t2.nom_niveau = ?))
bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Etudiant sql="SELECT t0.id_etu,  t0.nom_etu, t0.prenom_etu, t0.ddn_etu FROM GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.etudiant t0, GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.niveau t2, GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.InscrireClasse t1 WHERE ((t1.id_niveau = t2.id_niveau.t2.id_niveau) AND (t2.nom_niveau = ?))")
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:378)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:        Cannot call methods on int.
    Error Code: 258
Call: SELECT t0.id_etu, t0.nom_etu, t0.prenom_etu, t0.ddn_etu FROM GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.etudiant t0, GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.niveau t2, GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.InscrireClasse t1 WHERE ((t1.id_niveau = t2.id_niveau.t2.id_niveau) AND (t2.nom_niveau = ?))
bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Etudiant sql="SELECT t0.id_etu, t0.nom_etu, t0.prenom_etu, t0.ddn_etu FROM GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.etudiant t0, GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.niveau t2, GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.InscrireClasse t1 WHERE ((t1.id_niveau = t2.id_niveau.t2.id_niveau) AND (t2.nom_niveau = ?))")
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:682)
...
```

AND if I try to switch positions writing **n**.idNiveau = **i**.idNiveau instead of i.idNiveau = n.idNiveau

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6076] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Object comparisons can only be used with    OneToOneMappings.  Other mapping comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons. 
Mapping:   [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[idNiveau-->GESTION_DES_NOTES.dbo.niveau.id_niveau]] 
Expression: [
Query Key idNiveau
 Base Entity_classes.Niveau]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Etudiant jpql="SELECT e.idEtu, e.nomEtu, e.prenomEtu,e.ddnEtu
```

FROM Etudiant e,InscrireClasse i, Niveau n 
WHERE n.idNiveau = i.idNiveau AND n.nomNiveau='Master 1'")

Comment: do you have a property `InscrireClasse.niveau`?

Comment: @wero  Nope. In the Class InscrireClasse I have a property idNiveau___ and      Niveau is another class with property idNiveau and nom_niveau.   (idNiveau is a primary key in Niveau and Referenced key or Foreign key in InscrireClasse)

Comment: How can anyone comment on that without the classes?

Comment: @NeilStockton   Ouch I was so disappointed I deleted the project. Could not find anything on my own.